# Infragistics UltraGrid automatically creating columns

Tags: winforms, infragistics, ultrawingrid

In a support post from Infragistics they write that by manually defining columns in the `UltraGrid` editor there will be no "auto create columns" made but that's not true. I can see my few manually defined columns but after setting the `DataSource` to a list of elements, columns for all properties are being created. Am I doing something wrong? I am using Release 2023.1 with VS 2022.

In the XAM version (`XamDataGrid`) there is a property "AutoGenerateColumns" - where is that on `UltraGrid`? The data schema editor would not make any sense if the data source then always overrides what was defined there.

Comment: What you did in the code to **manually define columns**?

Comment: @Jackdaw: "by manually defining columns >> in the UltraGrid editor <<"

Answer (score 1):

The disappointing answer from Infragistics support today:

"**There is no way to prevent the grid from generating all of the columns** that exist in the data source. By design the grid will create bands and columns based on the structure of the data source.

What you can do is use the grid's InitializeLayout event and hide the columns you don't want the user to see."

So I'd better chose another controls suite.

Comment: So, you still can _**use the grid's `InitializeLayout` event and hide the columns you don't want the user to see**_. This is what I did once.

Comment: @Jackdaw: Yes, but why do we have this kind of extra work to do in a 1300+$ controls suite.